# Swap function for a sorting algorithm doesn't work with parameter from the sorting function.

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

So I have a selection sort function on another header file taking an array argument coming from source.cpp
This should sort the array but when i use the swap function it doens't work.

```
class selection
{
public:
    void selectionSort(int a[],int b[], int n);
    void swap(int a, int b);
};
void selection::selectionSort(int a[], int b[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        int iMin = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] < a[iMin])
                iMin = j;
        }
        swap(a[i], a[iMin]);
        swap(b[i], b[iMin]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
        cout << b[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void selection::swap(int a, int b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Meanwhile, when i dont use a function and just simply write the swap inside the loop like this, (replacing swap with this code)

```
int temp = a[i];
a[i] = a[iMin];
a[iMin] = temp;

int temp2 = b[i]
b[i] = b[iMin];
b[iMin] = temp2;
```

it works perfectly.

Additional info is that i have a struct in source.cpp which has two array members that are passed as a[] and b[], n is just the number of data being sorted.

Comment: Your `swap` function does nothing. Your problem can be reduced to: `void f(int x) { x = 42; } int main() { int a = 0; f(a); cout << a << "\n"; }`

Comment: Change swap to use references: void swap(int & a, int  &b);

Answer (score 2):

Change your swap function to take in references, instead of values:

```
void selection::swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

When a function takes in a value, the object is copied before passed over and is not affected in the callee.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, `selection::swap()` taking arguments by value. Since it is supposed to modify the value of the receiving parameter by swapping them, it should take the references:

```
void selection::swap(int &a, int &b)
```